# How do I shape multivariate data for input to LSTM

Tags: python, lstm

## What I am trying to achieve.

I am trying to predict opening price of Natural Gas ("NG Open") from multiple input parameters per table below. I have followed some tutorials but they don't explain the reason behind a particular format.The code is working after multiple trial and error but need to have some understanding on re-shaping data.

## Dataset - Only few lines.

```
Contract    NGLast   NGOpen NGHigh NGLow NGVolumes COOpen COHigh COLow
2018-12-01  4.487    4.50   4.60   4.03  100,000   56.00  58.00  50.00
2019-01-01  4.450    4.52   4.61   4.11  93000     51.00  53.00  45.00
```

## Code

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  from keras.layers import Dense
  from keras.models import Sequential
  from keras.layers import LSTM
  import date time

  from keras import metrics
  from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

  data = pd.read_excel("C:\Futures\Futures.xls")

  data['Contract'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Contract'],unit='s').dt.date
  data['NG Last'] = data['NG Last'].str.rstrip('s')
  data['CO Last'] = data['CO Last'].str.rstrip('s')

  COHigh =  np.array([data.iloc[:,8]])
  COLow  =  np.array([data.iloc[:,9]])
  NGLast =  np.array([data.iloc[:,1]])
  NGOpen =  np.array([data.iloc[:,2]])
  NGHigh =  np.array([data.iloc[:,3]])

  X = np.concatenate([COHigh,COLow, NGLast,NGOpen], axis =0)
  X = np.transpose(X)
  Y = NGHigh
  Y = np.transpose(Y)
  scaler = MinMaxScaler()
  scaler.fit(X)
  X = scaler.transform(X)
  scaler.fit(Y)
  Y = scaler.transform(Y)

  **X = np.reshape(X,(X.shape[0],1,X.shape[1]))**
  print(X.shape)

  model = Sequential()
  **model.add(LSTM(100,activation='tanh',input_shape=(1,4),** recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
  model.add(Dense(1))

 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics = [metrics.mae])
 model.fit(X,Y,epochs = 10,batch_size=1,verbose=2)

 Predict = model.predict(X,verbose=1)
```

## Question

What is the reasoning behind the code marked in astrix above?

1> I have four columns as input so shouldn't it be **X = np.reshape(X,(X.shape[0],1,X.shape[1], X.Shape[2],X.shape[3]))**? and so on for all the columns considered as inputs?

2> I need explanation of parameters in this line below. **model.add(LSTM(100,activation='tanh',input_shape=(1,4),** recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your data is currently an array of shape (x,4) where x is the number of rows. So in the toy data you provide, `X.shape` should return (2,4). If you look at the LSTM line later on, you'll note that it's looking for tensor of shape (1,4) -- that's the `input_shape` parameter. The `np.reshape` line is what gets you there. It's converting your 2-d array into a 3-d one. Again, with your example, `X.shape` will return (2,1,4) after you reshape it. Basically, you now have a list of length 2 of (1,4) arrays, which matches what the LSTM layer wants.
2. I'd recommend taking a look at the Keras [documentation on the LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#LSTM), but here's basically what's happening. 100 is the number of units (or neurons) that this layer will have. Input shape is noted above. The activation is the function that will be used to calculate the output for each neuron. The tanh function is pretty standard in this basic setup, but others are possible Take a look at the list of [activations](https://keras.io/activations/) that Keras provides out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. My follow-up question is why can't I use X.Shape to covert directly to 3D and make this happen only in next step?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Where do you want to do this? `X.shape` is simply a value and as far as I know, neither `np.concatenate` nor `np.transpose` would allow you to do this.

Comment: You could save a little bit by combining the `np.concatenate` and `np.transpose` lines: `X = np.transpose(np.concatenate([COHigh, COLow, NGLast, NGOpen], axis=0))` and the fit/transform lines: `X = scaler.fit_transform(X)`

Comment: One last question : How do I convert the predicted values back to original state such as NG Open values say $3.50, $4.50, $2.90 and so on? I am not able to find this part anywhere.

Comment: That's what your value `Predict` should be. However, since you converted your training `Y` to be binary, the interpretation of those values isn't clear. On that note, you almost certainly want two different `MinMaxScaler`s for `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I would like to introduce one more column into my model but the problem is the lag between two rows is weekly. The change in value of this weekly data impacts the daily prices which is why is important. I would also like to include weather. Do you know how this can be achieved? I tried finding this information but in vain.